# Using create-react-app and output ES2017 code

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm creating a new reactjs project using the `create-react-app`. Currently the application should support only modern browsers, However the file generated by the webpack / build process is using ES5. After eject I have fully access to webpack.config and tsconfig file, but I didn`t find the cofiguration to achieve this.

Comment: Which version of the create-react-app you have installed? create-react-app --version
Currently I have version 3.0.1 and I checked, there is no chance that it will work on older browsers, eg IE11.
Currently, you can control in the package.json which browsers are to be supported.
`"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },`

Comment: If I set browserlist it generate polyfill`s to a  target browser?  Example: don`t need do transpile async await or fetch in modern  chrome version.